# A function that is differentiable at a single point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, self-learning

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2  & x \in \mathbf{Q}, \\ 0  & x \notin \mathbf{Q} \end{cases} $$

$f$ is continuous only at $0$ and now I need to show that at this point it is also differentiable. So

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

How do I continue from here? All suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Note that $|f(x)| \le x^2$ for all $x$.

Comment: Well, you are showing that $\lim_{h\to 0} {f(h)-f(0) \over h} = 0$ which tells you that it is differentiable and that the derivative is zero.

Comment: @copper.hat We have shown that $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} \leq  0$. How can we infer from that, that the derivative is $0$?

Comment: No, the above shows that $\lim_{x \to 0} { f(x) \over x} = 0$, from which the result follows.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm still a bit confused as to how. I'll think it over some more

Comment: I added an answer, hopefully that helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|f(x)| \le x^2$, we have $f(0) = 0$ and  $\left| {f(x) - f(0) \over x } \right| \le |x|$. This gives $\lim_{x \to 0} \left| {f(x) - f(0) \over x } \right| = 0$. Hence $\lim_{x \to 0}  {f(x) - f(0) \over x }  = 0$. Since $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}  {f(x) - f(0) \over x } = 0$, we see that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and the derivative is $f'(0) = 0$.

**Aside**: If $|x_n| \to 0$, we must have $x_n \to 0$. This follows from $-|x_n| \le x_n \le |x_n|$.